# zabbix не получается настроить автообнаружение

Tags: zabbix

Поставил zabbix 3.4.8.
не могу настроить автообнаружение
Что я делаю не так?
[image: Обнаружение]

[image: Действие]

[image: операции]

Comment: внезапно `zabbix` умеет писать свои  логи в какой-нибудь `LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log`, а также управлять уровнем информации в выводе логов `DebugLevel=3`. Ставьте 4-й или 5-й уровень и смотрите логи, возможно найдете ответ.

Comment: cannot send list of active checks to 176.17.122.19: host [ws1_cl4] not found

Comment: Ответ не нашёл.